# Order of Thumbnails on LinkedIn ShareArticle Link

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph, yoast

I'm trying to implement a "Share" button which shares my current Wordpress post to LinkedIn and I'm using their [standard linkedin.com/shareArticle link](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin) and it's working great, except that the thumbnail that shows up first is one that has been automatically crawled on the page, rather then the og:image that I'm telling it to use. I'm using Yoast SEO to create the OpenGraph information, which is working great, and I've used [Facebook Lint Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) to verify this.

The issue is that the og:image is showing up as the second image, not the first image when the share link is created. **How do I prioritize the og:image to be the first image?** Or, **is there a CSS class or something I can add to the other images on my post so they are disregarded from LinkedIn Share all together**?

Note in the below screenshot that it shows the image I want as "2 of 2", instead of "1 of 2".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the image defined in the `<og:image>` tag does not fulfill the requirements of LinkedIn. Here are the image requirements specific to the LinkedIn sharing module as described in the “[Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)” article:

- Max file size: 5 MB
- Minimum image dimensions: 1200 (w) x 627 (h) pixels
- Recommended ratio: 1.91:1

Your image is just 257px tall.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Any idea why the intended image still shows up the preview, but as picture 2 of 2, even when it doesn't meet LinkedIn's OG requirements?

Comment: Unfortunately LinkedIn caches the queried page for a couple of days, so even if you change the code, it won't make any change on LinkedIn at once. To test the effect of the new setup, you could append a fake query parameter to the end of your url, like `http://my.cached.url/?v=1`.

Comment: Other images will still continue to show up in the image selector of the preview, but the image set to `<og:image>` is only respected as the first image if it meets the requirements.

Comment: What's interesting is that they have conflicting image-size requirements. The page you referenced shows 1200px (w) x 627px (h), but the official developer document for "Share on LinkedIn" says 80px (w) x 150px (h). https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

Comment: That is interesting indeed! 80x150 seems to be way to small though. Besides that, I have tested this, and it seemed to respect `<og:image>` only when resolution was higher than 1200x627. Have you tried that?

Comment: Weird! I cloned the site to my staging server and when you click "Share on LinkedIn" on the staging site, the first/main image that loads in the share dialog is correct, the featured image/post thumbnail. For some reason it doesn't show this image on the live site, just staging.

Live Site: https://blogs.constellation.com/customers-community/constellation-community-roundup/

Staging Site: https://constellationm.staging.wpengine.com/customers-community/constellation-community-roundup/

Comment: I've cloned your page (static html) too, but the featured image still shows up as 2/2. The strange thing is, that on your prod site, there are only 2 preview images parsed by LinkedIn, while on the staging there are 3 images.

Comment: guys is there any way show only ONE image, from the meta tag, and not other 2 random images from the page?

Comment: @mcmxc Unfortunately, I don't think you can control that, as LinkedIn scrapes the page and grabs the image links from the source.

Comment: that's really stupid logic, I don't understand why it takes 2 more random images from the page.. Where did you get this info?

Comment: This is just a guess based on my experience, as I didn't find specific info on that one. But [according to others](https://www.addtoany.com/ext/meta-tags/#linkedin) too, LinkedIn does not performs well in this regard.